# new to python having trouble printing 4 variables

Tags: python

```
adding = int(5+3)
subtract = int(10-2)
multiplication = int(2*4)
division = int(16/2)
print (str(adding,"\n",subtract,"\n",multiplication,"\n",division))
```

im getting a typeError: TypeError: str() takes at most 3 arguments (7 given)

Comment: Why is the `str()` even there?

Comment: `print (adding,subtract,multiplication,division, sep="\n")`

Comment: Take out `str()` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Just change this piece of code from this

```
print (str(adding,"\n",subtract,"\n",multiplication,"\n",division))
```

To this.

```
print (adding,"\n",subtract,"\n",multiplication,"\n",division)
```

**Reason**: str() is a typecast method. You don't need to typecast each and everything.

**For Reference**:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-casting-in-python-implicit-and-explicit-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Think of str as a function that takes in a variable and converts it into a string. Passing multiple variables to str() separated by comma will not apply string function to each variable. It will instead mean that they are arguments to the function.
If you want to convert each variable into

```
adding = str(int(5+3))
subtract = str(int(10-2))
multiplication = str(int(2*4))
division = str(int(16/2))
print (adding,"\n",subtract,"\n",multiplication,"\n",division)
```

Note that print function accepts multiple arguments for printing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an `integer` to `string`, you need to use `str()`  each variables separately.
Also, you can use `+` as `concat` operator to avoid extra space.

```
print(str(adding)+"\n"+str(subtract)+"\n"+str(multiplication)+"\n"+str(division))
```